# How do I get items from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage

In my app I've got 2 functions to work with localStorage. 
When I add the first and second items, it works properly, but when it is the third item, it gives an error.

Here are the functions:

```
    w.getLocalStorage = function() {
    var c = localStorage.getItem('cities');
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(c);
    return c ? arr : [];
}

w.setLocalStorage = function(data, googleData, cities, name) {
    if (data) {
        city.name = data.name; 
        city.coord.lat = data.coord.lat;
        city.coord.lon = data.coord.lon;
        cities.push(JSON.stringify(city));
        // console.log(city);
        localStorage.setItem("cities", cities);

    } else if (googleData) {
        city.name = name; 
        city.coord.lat = googleData.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        city.coord.lon = googleData.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
        console.log('cities', cities);
        cities.push(JSON.stringify(city));
        // console.log(cities, city);
        localStorage.setItem("cities", cities);
    }
}
```

Here is what it returns for the first 2 items:

```
    Array[1] 
0 : "{"name":"Pushcha-Voditsa","coord":{"lat":50.45,"lon":30.5}}"
1 : "{"name":"Kyiv","coord":{"lat":50.4501,"lon":30.5234}}"
```

Here is what when the third items is added:

```
Array[1]
0 : "{"name":"Pushcha-Voditsa","coord":{"lat":50.45,"lon":30.5}}, {"name":"Kyiv","coord":{"lat":50.4501,"lon":30.5234}}"
1 : "{"name":"Kyiv","coord":{"lat":50.4501,"lon":30.5234}}"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: "it gives an error" Perhaps the error is meant to provide information :-? What does it say?

Comment: Always read the docs first. From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API: 
"The keys and the values are always strings". You need to convert the values to and from strings using something like the json api

Answer (score 1):

As you can only store string in `localStorage`, to persist object convert them in stringified format using [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method and on retrieval use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to parses the JSON string to construct the JavaScript value or object.

Here are the code snippet, which require attention. You should persist stringified `cities` data

```
cities.push(city);
localStorage.setItem("cities", JSON.stringify(cities));
```

While retrieval, parse it JavaScript object

```
var cities = localStorage.getItem('cities');
var c = cities ? JSON.parse(cities) || [];
```

Comment: Answer is fine, but just to clarify: you can't save directly an object in localstorage, so you need to convert it to `String`. Once you get the `String`, you can safely store it. Then to retrieve it, you should conver the `String` again to an object. That's why you need the functions `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`